# How to deal with fractional response on panel data?

Tags: python, fractions, panel-data

I have panel data which the response variable is fractional between 0 and 1, Initially I modeled my data using simple fractional logit model=sm.Logit(y,x) ,results=model.fit(cov_type='HC0') in Python but since my data is panel I needed a model to capture random effects. Does anyone know how can I do that in Python?

Comment: Asking simply for recommendations on packages, tools, etc is considered off-topic for SO. Take a look again at [ask]. If you're tagging 3 distinct languages, it's also way too broad a question

Comment: Note that this would've been more-or-less on topic just for SAS - as SAS doesn't (for the most part) have libraries, but has functionality like this built in (so you're just asking for "how to do X in SAS"). You'd still want to make it a better question - do some research in the basic SAS regression/modelling procedures and explain what you've tried (it's okay if you don't come up with PROC GLIMMIX on your own, but at least explain why PROC LOGISTIC, GLM, etc. don't work), and provide a bit more detail/context.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `proc glimmix.` Check out the SAS note below.

https://support.sas.com/kb/56/992.html

> Estimation of model parameters using this quasi-likelihood can be done using the GLIMMIX and NLMIXED procedures. The fractional logistic model is a linear logistic model and is most easily fit in PROC GLIMMIX. Since proportions are bounded between 0 and 1, it is natural to use the logit link function. To estimate the scale parameter, the random *residual*; statement is specified. Predicted proportions and confidence limits are saved to a data set by the OUTPUT statement.

```
proc glimmix data=damage;
    model y = lconc / dist=binomial link=logit s;
    random _residual_;
    output out=fracout pred(ilink)=pred lcl(ilink)=lower ucl(ilink)=upper;
run;
```